# how to check browser popup is going to close

Tags: javascript, jquery

I write code to open a popup in new window. I open this window for few seconds after that it will close automatically.What I want is if somebody close it before that limit of time. I will detect it and show him message. Here is code I am using

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var myWindow;
    $("#idview").click(function() {
        var vidurl = $('#vurl').val();
        counter();
        myWindow = window.open(vidurl, "popupWindow", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");

    });

    function counter() {
        var n = $('.c').attr('id');
        var c = n;
        $('.c').text(c);
        setInterval(function() {
            c++;
            if (c <= 41) {
                $('.c').text(c);
            }
            if (c == 41) {
                $('.c').text(n);
            }
        }, 1000);
    }



    setInterval(function() {
        myWindow.close();
    }, 45000);

    window.onbeforeunload = closingCode;
function closingCode(){
   alert('hitme');
   return null;
}


});
```

I try to use `window.ununload` but it is not working. can anybody please tell me how to get if somebody is going to close the browser popup?

Thanks

Comment: you can use `onbeforeunload ` to check if anyone closing the popup

Comment: you can check that is also used in code @RAUSHANKUMAR not working

Comment: You need to bind the onbeforeunload event to the window AFTER it is opened. so move the code to inside the click event . take a look on my answer @azadchouhan

Comment: @azadchouhan the pop-up window url is in the same domain as the parent page  ?

Comment: check this http://chandigarhpropertyonline.com/Shareit/Youtubeviews here is my web page on which I am working viewyoutube.js is is my js file

Comment: your opening youtube  url that's not the same domain as the parent page . so The best you could do is open a document in your domain that then loads the remote URL in an iframe, or reads it in via server scripts and renders it from there.

Comment: yes I want it to be open in new window not under the parent window

Answer (score 2):

You   can use onbeforeunload like this :

```
 window.onbeforeunload = function (e) {
  var e = e || window.event;

};
```

More reference : 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeunload

Even possible duplicate of : [javascript detect browser close tab/close browser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3888902/javascript-detect-browser-close-tab-close-browser)

Answer (score 1):

**1st :** You need to bind the `onbeforeunload` event to the window `AFTER` it is `opened`.

**2nd :** so move the  `onbeforeunload` event code to inside the `click event` function

**3rd :**  `Window.onbeforeunload`  change to `myWindow.onbeforeunload`

```
    var myWindow;
    $("#idview").click(function() {
        //var vidurl = $('#vurl').val();
        var vidurl = "google.com";
        counter();
        myWindow = window.open(vidurl, "popupWindow", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");

         myWindow.onbeforeunload = function closingCode(){
                               alert('hitme');
                               return null;
                            }

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/rs01x0oy/

```js
var myWindow;
$("#idview").click(function() {
    var vidurl = $('#vurl').val();
    counter();
    myWindow = window.open(vidurl, "popupWindow", "width=600, height=400, scrollbars=yes");
    myWindow.onbeforeunload = function(){
      console.log("Closed");
    };
});

function counter() {
    var n = $('.c').attr('id');
    var c = n;
    $('.c').text(c);
    setInterval(function() {
        c++;
        if (c <= 41) {
            $('.c').text(c);
        }
        if (c == 41) {
            $('.c').text(n);
        }
    }, 1000);
}



setInterval(function() {
    myWindow.close();
}, 45000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="idview" type="submit">
Submit
</button>
```

Comment: yes its working in the fiddle but not working in my web page.. i donot  know why its working

Comment: I need the same thing you did here. even I am not getting any error in console too..

Comment: Please share your HTML & entire JS code.... This is one more version https://jsfiddle.net/rs01x0oy/1/ ... Update the setInterval.

Comment: the js code is all I paste above..and for html I use <a class="campaign_button bg_red" id="idview">View</a> in my html template

Comment: I tested in my local, it working perfectly. Check the order of JS files... jQuery library file should be included first then your own JS file... Don't forget to include $(document).ready(function(){}); in your JS code...